# Is the iron loss of an iron core transformer twice the mass of the iron core?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, electrical

In a mathematical problem related to transformer loss I've found Iron loss = Mass of iron x 2.

If this is true, then how kg is converted into watts.

Comment: Wherever you found that, it's not a sensible formula, since as you noticed, the units aren't even compatible. Let alone does it make any sense that losses would be a fixed value depending only on the core mass; at the very least, the power put into the transformer needs to play a role, too, otherwise you could generate losses without using energy. Perpetuum mobiles don't exist. So, there's nothing to answer here: False claim.

Comment: I have edited your title; please double-check that I haven't changed the meaning.

Comment: No, it's the cube root of the mass in [shekels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_measurement)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't link to the document that had the original formula and, given that the original formula has no context, the question therefore is poor quality.

Comment: The only way to convert mass into energy is \$E=mc^2\$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in the title -- no.

Iron losses depend on a large number of factors, and part of transformer design is predicting iron losses and making a tradeoff between iron and copper losses.

The actual amount of loss depends on the transformer geometry, the core material used, the lamination thickness (if it's a steel core), the frequency of operation, etc.

The **target** amount of loss depends on how efficient the transformer needs to be (or how hot it can get) vs. the cost to make it, how large it ends up being, whether it'll need external cooling, etc.

You may have stumbled across someone's *guideline* that says that for *their particular field* one wants to make the iron losses roughly equal to some constant times the core mass.  But without knowing what that field is or what drives that guideline, I don't think it makes any sense to say it's a universal constant.

Answer (score 1):

How is kg converted into watts?

By making some assumptions. Presumably the author had some operating field in mind (loss increases with the maximum field applied), an operating frequency (loss increases with the frequency), and a particular grade of core material (as you spend more money on thinner laminations, exotic alloys, and careful heat treatment you can reduce the losses somewhat below those of a cheaper core).

Once you find out what these assumptions are, you can make sense of his watts per kg multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, typically you might want to equalize the copper loss with the iron loss in an optimized transformer design, but other than that, this makes no sense at all.